# Diiference between Page Factory and Result Page Factory in Magento

Tags: layout, factory

What is the use of PageFactory and ResultPageFactory in Magento?
Major difference between both and for what both are used for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only `\Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory` class

ResultPageFactory is used like alias in m2

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory as ResultPageFactory
```